# Disable ipv4 for a specific process

Tags: networking, ip

Is it possible to disable IPv4 on a per-process basis?

I would like that a specific process only uses IPv6 for resolving DNS and then for making TCP connections, but without disabling IPv4 for the whole machine or for any of the network interfaces.

Comment: Not an answer, but some tools have command line flags to force IPV6, so it’s worth checking if your program has that option

Comment: It depends on the software/process - you cannot disable IPv4 on a per process process typically though